# null id in Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I've created a new Movie ContentType with a Taxonomy Field attached (using migrations). The Taxonomy name and Terms get created using `IEventHandler` `Enabled` event.

I log in to the Dashboard, I can see the Taxonomy field created with all terms.

Now, I try to create a new `Movie` ContentItem, I get the following exception.

Any idea please?

```
2014-02-27 13:44:38,996 [24] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - An unexpected exception was caught
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord (Data, ContentType_id) VALUES (?, ?)] ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeLockTimeoutException: SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock. The default lock time is 2000ms for devices and 5000ms for desktops. The default lock timeout can be increased in the connection string using the ssce: default lock timeout property. [ Session id = 2,Thread id = 9324,Process id = 4488,Table name = Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord,Conflict type = x lock (x blocks),Resource = PAG (idx): 1066 ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr& pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:line 203
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Id\Insert\AbstractSelectingDelegate.cs:line 38
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Id\Insert\AbstractSelectingDelegate.cs:line 47
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 2575
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 3035
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Action\EntityIdentityInsertAction.cs:line 75
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:line 136
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractSaveEventListener.cs:line 259
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractSaveEventListener.cs:line 187
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractSaveEventListener.cs:line 119
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cs:line 162
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveEventListener.cs:line 27
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cs:line 148
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveEventListener.cs:line 21
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cs:line 53
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 2673
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 485
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Create(T entity) in c:\Dev\Repos\orchardfeb\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 96
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Create(T entity) in c:\Dev\Repos\orchardfeb\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 36
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.Create(ContentItem contentItem, VersionOptions options) in c:\Dev\Repos\orchardfeb\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 511
   at Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.AdminController.CreatePOST(String id, String returnUrl, Action`1 conditionallyPublish) in c:\Dev\Repos\orchardfeb\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Contents\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 233
   at Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.AdminController.CreateAndPublishPOST(String id, String returnUrl) in c:\Dev\Repos\orchardfeb\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Contents\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 224
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__10()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
2014-02-27 13:44:39,054 [24] NHibernate.AssertionFailure - An AssertionFailure occurred - this may indicate a bug in NHibernate or in your custom types.
NHibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

Comment: Looks like a corrupted database.

Comment: I had a similar problem a few days ago. Restarting the server worked for me.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't creating the Table for my part as I thought using Infoset doesn't require creating the Table. I had to create the Table and the error vanishes. HTH

Answer (score 1):

As written [here](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2007/11/14/nhibernate---null-id-in-entry-dont-flush-the-session.aspx), this means that some error occured and NHibernate failed to save the record and make the id for it, but semi-persisted the record and tried to save it again... without `ID`. The underlying error varies, it can be due to missing table as in your case, a typo in column name, any inconsistence between model and migrations (in Orchard or similar framework - I had some nullable/not nullable mismatch) using reserved words, a unique constraint... There is no bulletproof solution, you must find (debugging software is a must and logs your friend) and solve the cause.